# Create a group from two columns

Tags: crystal-reports, report, grouping

I have this:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
Water    1        2€
Water    2        3€
Water    2        5€
Milk     1        8€
Milk     1        4€
Milk     2        10€
Milk     3        1€
```

I am trying to group a column and sum the column to the side referring to the price.

And I want this:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
Water    1        2€
Water    2        8€
Milk     1        12€
Milk     2        10€
Milk     3        1€
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the datatype of `Column2` is numeric, create a formula-field with the following content and then create a group from this field:

```
{Table.Column1} + "###" + CStr({Table.Column2})
```

Now just create the sum for `Column3`.

If necessary, change the string `###` to something else, that will not appear in `Column1` and `Column2`.